# How to use SimplexSolver or SimplexOptimizer in java apache math?

Tags: java, math, optimization, apache-commons-math

I'm trying to use the apache commons math library version 3.5+ to solve an optimization problem. Basically, I'm trying to fit a (gamma) distribution to some data points. I can't seem to find any simple examples of how to use the new (version 3.5) optimization tools, such as SimplexSolver, SimplexOptimizer, or OptimizationData, to solve a trivial optimization problem.

Similar questions have been asked here before, but all the answers seem to be for older version of apache math - in 3.5 things were restructured and none of the example code I could find works.

Does anyone have a working example how to use the new optimizers or solvers? I'm most interested in SimplexOptimizer, but at this point anything would be useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, the optimizers may be hard to use: Lots of parameters, of which different combinations are required for the different types of optimizers, and they are all hidden in the generic `OptimizationData` array that they receive. Unless you start matching the code with the papers that they refer to, you can hardly get any results out of them whatsoever.

I also wanted to use some of thes solvers/optimizers a try occasionally, the main source of reliable, working ""examples"" for me turned out to be the *unit tests* of these classes, which usually are quite elaborate and cover many cases. For example, regarding the `SimplexOptimizer`, you may want to have a look at the [`org/apache/commons/math4/optim/nonlinear/scalar/noderiv/`](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-math.git;a=tree;f=src/test/java/org/apache/commons/math4/optim/nonlinear/scalar/noderiv) test cases, containing the test classes  `SimplexOptimizerMultiDirectionalTest.java` and `SimplexOptimizerNelderMeadTest.java`.

<sub>(Sorry, maybe this is not what you expected or hoped for, but ... I found these tests tremendously helpful when I tried to figure out which `OptimizationData` these optimizers actually need...)</sub>

> EDIT

Just for reference, a complete example, extracted from one of the basic unit tests:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.MultivariateFunction;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.InitialGuess;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.MaxEval;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.PointValuePair;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.GoalType;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.ObjectiveFunction;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.noderiv.NelderMeadSimplex;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.noderiv.SimplexOptimizer;
import org.apache.commons.math3.util.FastMath;

public class SimplexOptimizerExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SimplexOptimizer optimizer = new SimplexOptimizer(1e-10, 1e-30);
        final FourExtrema fourExtrema = new FourExtrema();

        final PointValuePair optimum =
            optimizer.optimize(
                new MaxEval(100), 
                new ObjectiveFunction(fourExtrema), 
                GoalType.MINIMIZE, 
                new InitialGuess(new double[]{ -3, 0 }), 
                new NelderMeadSimplex(new double[]{ 0.2, 0.2 }));

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(optimum.getPoint()) + " : "
            + optimum.getSecond());
    }

    private static class FourExtrema implements MultivariateFunction
    {
        // The following function has 4 local extrema.
        final double xM = -3.841947088256863675365;
        final double yM = -1.391745200270734924416;
        final double xP = 0.2286682237349059125691;
        final double yP = -yM;
        final double valueXmYm = 0.2373295333134216789769; // Local maximum.
        final double valueXmYp = -valueXmYm; // Local minimum.
        final double valueXpYm = -0.7290400707055187115322; // Global minimum.
        final double valueXpYp = -valueXpYm; // Global maximum.

        public double value(double[] variables)
        {
            final double x = variables[0];
            final double y = variables[1];
            return (x == 0 || y == 0) ? 0 : FastMath.atan(x)
                * FastMath.atan(x + 2) * FastMath.atan(y) * FastMath.atan(y)
                / (x * y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks perfect! Thanks. I think each optimizer takes its own set of 'OptimizationData' items, which cna be almost anything. Funny that there's not a nice list anywhere of which solvers / optimizers expect which items.

Comment: For Math 3, the tests are: https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-math.git;a=blob;f=src/test/java/org/apache/commons/math3/optim/linear/SimplexSolverTest.java;h=452bd7d48469cbca74a3532c47bf6076c8a459af;hb=refs/heads/3.6.1-release