# Apache commons math optimization get best solution each iteration

Tags: java, math, optimization, apache-commons-math

Apache Commons Math has optimization classes that can optimize some objective function, and typically a maximum number of evaluations has to be set for an optimizer.

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/32532514/3229995 there is a working small Java example of a full functional NelderMeadSimplex with `MaxEval(100)` setting the maximal evaluations.

How can I obtain the current solution during each evaluation step of an optimizer such as NelderMeadSimplex?

The code referenced runs and prints out only the final solution (or throws a TooManyEvaluationsException and does not print any solution so far if the number in `MaxEval(100)` is too low), but I cannot find a class method or field that can help to obtain the current solution of each eval step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, and as far as I could derive from looking at the source code of the implementation, there is no direct, built-in way to obtain the intermediate results.

There are some interfaces involved that are (supposed to be) called during each evaluation. Particularly, there is the [`ConvergenceChecker`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/optim/ConvergenceChecker.html) interface. One comparatively clean solution **could** be to implement this interface accordingly (by deriving from one of its implementing classes). But as far as I know, there is no strict *requirement* for each optimization algorithm to use this interface (and even less to *reall* call it during each evaluation step).

Once, I wanted to achieve the same goal: To "log" the intermediate steps of the optimization, to [visualize an optimization process](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69930/paint-starry-night-objectively-in-1kb-of-code/70230#70230). I solved this ... *very* pragmatically: The only thing that one can be sure of is that the `MultivariateFunction` will have to be evaluated at each point. This is, in some sense, the place where one can insert a hook into the optimization black box. So eventually, I created a wrapper around the `MultivariateFunction`:

```
private static MultivariateFunction createLogging(
    final MultivariateFunction delegate)
{
    return new MultivariateFunction()
    {
        @Override
        public double value(double[] point)
        {
            double result = delegate.value(point);
            System.out.println("Evaluated "+
                Arrays.toString(point)+" to "+result);
            return result;
        }
    };
}
```

Then, replacing any

```
new ObjectiveFunction(multivariateFunction)
```

with

```
new ObjectiveFunction(createLogging(multivariateFunction)),
```

will cause the optimization process to be logged.

I do not *recommend* to solve it like this, but depending on the goal and application case, it may be an option, at least.